# get keys of matching items in array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to work through an issue with a CSV report.  I am trying to find specific information based on strings within the report based on what the user chooses.  It is a report containing information about many different events and dates (an event could have multiple dates and so would be repeated for each date resulting in multiple occurrences of the event name)

The user selects a number of performances (specific event/date combo) and these are added to an array using the `eventId` number for each:

e.g.

```
$eventArray = array(232 => 'event one', 21 => 'event four', 443 = 'event one');
```

Each being `eventid => eventName` (there can be duplicate event names as they would have different dates in the system).

I'm going through the report with the following:

```
       $file_handle = fopen("$reportUrl", "r");
       while(!feof($file_handle))
        {
           $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 20000);
           include('logic/finance_logic.php');                                      
        }
       fclose($file_handle);
```

And so for each row in the CSV it is running the code in the `finance_logic.php` file.  The part I'm having difficulty with is the following:

```
// CHECK TO SEE IF THE FIRST LINE IS AN EVENT IN THE ARRAY (NOTE, THERE CAN BE DOUPLICATES)
if(in_array(trim(substr($line_of_text[0],6)), $eventArray)) 
    {
        $f = 1;
        // get event name
        $eventName = trim(substr($line_of_text[0],6));
        // date of event
        $eventDateArray = getEventDateArray($eventName);
    }
    if(isset($f))
        {
            $dateSearch = checkDateInArray($line_of_text[0], $eventDateArray);
            if($f == 1 && $dateSearch[0] == 'found')
                {
                    $eventId = $dateSearch[1];
                    $f = 2;
                }
```

The `checkDateInArray` function is the following:

```
function checkDateInArray($date, $array)
{
    if(is_array($array))
        {
            foreach($array as $key => $d)
                {
                    if (strpos($date, $d) !== false) 
                        {
                            // return array with first value 'found' and second being the key which is the event id
                            return array('found', $key);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

NOTE: the time will not always have GMT at the end as it depends on the location so this needs to be ignored when comparing the dates also.

All of which leads to a messy fix for something I'm sure is much simpler another way.  The one way I was considering is that the event array created is the `eventId => eventName` but the `eventId` is linked with the `eventName` and `eventDate` in the database.  Is there a way I could create an `eventArray` which was `eventId => array('eventName', 'eventDate')` and then check to see if it is in these.  I'm not sure how to go about it.  Also, an example of the way the CSV is laid out is the following:

```
"Event: Event One"
""
"Performance Date:  15 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT"
""
"Venue: Theatre"
""
"Category: English Comedy"
"Discount","A",
"GENERAL ADMISSION",35.00,
"RESERVED",0.00,
"COMPLIMENTARY",0.00,
"SPECIAL",0.00,
"Holds","A","Face Value Amt",
"H: House Seats",16,16,
"Face Value Amt",,,
"--",,,
"Capacity",371,371,
""
"INT"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"GENERAL ADMISSION",119,4165.00,119,4165.00,
"Totals*",119,4165.00,119,4165.00,
""
"PBO"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"*SPECIAL",10,220.00,10,220.00,
"COMPLIMENTARY",4,0.00,4,0.00,
"GENERAL ADMISSION",22,770.00,22,770.00,
"RESERVED",0,0.00,0,0.00,
"Totals*",36,990.00,36,990.00,
""
"PHO"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"*GENERAL ADMISSION",0,0.00,0,0.00,
"*SPECIAL",42,940.00,42,940.00,
"COMPLIMENTARY",10,0.00,10,0.00,
"GENERAL ADMISSION",68,2380.00,68,2380.00,
"RESERVED",0,0.00,0,0.00,
"Totals*",120,3320.00,120,3320.00,
""
"PERFORMANCE TOTALS"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"*GENERAL ADMISSION",0,0.00,0,0.00,
"*SPECIAL",52,1160.00,52,1160.00,
"COMPLIMENTARY",14,0.00,14,0.00,
"GENERAL ADMISSION",209,7315.00,209,7315.00,
"RESERVED",0,0.00,0,0.00,
"Totals*",275,8475.00,275,8475.00,
""
"Abbreviated Performance Totals"
"Event","Performance Date","Discount","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
Event One,15 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,*GENERAL ADMISSION,0,0.00,
Event One,15 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,*SPECIAL,52,1160.00,
Event One,15 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,COMPLIMENTARY,14,0.00,
Event One,15 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,GENERAL ADMISSION,209,7315.00,
Event One,15 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,RESERVED,0,0.00,
,,,275,8475.00,
""
"Event: Event One"
""
"Performance Date:  16 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT+04:00"
""
"Venue: Theatre"
""
"Category: English Comedy"
"Discount","A",
"GENERAL ADMISSION",35.00,
"RESERVED",0.00,
"COMPLIMENTARY",0.00,
"SPECIAL",0.00,
""
"INT"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"GENERAL ADMISSION",203,7105.00,203,7105.00,
"Totals*",203,7105.00,203,7105.00,
""
"PBO"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"GENERAL ADMISSION",36,1260.00,36,1260.00,
"RESERVED",0,0.00,0,0.00,
"Totals*",36,1260.00,36,1260.00,
""
"PHO"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"COMPLIMENTARY",15,0.00,15,0.00,
"GENERAL ADMISSION",99,3465.00,99,3465.00,
"RESERVED",-9,0.00,-9,0.00,
"Totals*",105,3465.00,105,3465.00,
""
"PERFORMANCE TOTALS"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"COMPLIMENTARY",15,0.00,15,0.00,
"GENERAL ADMISSION",338,11830.00,338,11830.00,
"RESERVED",-9,0.00,-9,0.00,
"Totals*",344,11830.00,344,11830.00,
""
"Abbreviated Performance Totals"
"Event","Performance Date","Discount","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
Event One,16 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,COMPLIMENTARY,15,0.00,
Event One,16 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,GENERAL ADMISSION,338,11830.00,
Event One,16 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,RESERVED,-9,0.00,
,,,344,11830.00,
""
"Event: Event Four"
""
"Performance Date:  18 Feb 2013 07:30 PM BST"
""
"Venue: Theatre"
""
"Category: English Comedy"
"Discount","A",
"GENERAL ADMISSION",25.00,
"RESERVED",0.00,
"STUDENT",15.00,
"COMPLIMENTARY",0.00,
"Senior Citizen",10.00,
"SPECIAL",0.00,
""
"INT"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"GENERAL ADMISSION",79,1975.00,79,1975.00,
"Totals*",79,1975.00,79,1975.00,
""
"PBO"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"COMPLIMENTARY",2,0.00,2,0.00,
"GENERAL ADMISSION",32,800.00,32,800.00,
"RESERVED",0,0.00,0,0.00,
"Senior Citizen",4,40.00,4,40.00,
"Totals*",38,840.00,38,840.00,
""
"PHO"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"COMPLIMENTARY",10,0.00,10,0.00,
"GENERAL ADMISSION",100,2500.00,100,2500.00,
"RESERVED",0,0.00,0,0.00,
"STUDENT",4,60.00,4,60.00,
"Senior Citizen",2,20.00,2,20.00,
"Totals*",116,2580.00,116,2580.00,
""
"PERFORMANCE TOTALS"
"Discount","A","A Face Value Amt","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
"COMPLIMENTARY",12,0.00,12,0.00,
"GENERAL ADMISSION",211,5275.00,211,5275.00,
"RESERVED",0,0.00,0,0.00,
"STUDENT",4,60.00,4,60.00,
"Senior Citizen",6,60.00,6,60.00,
"Totals*",233,5395.00,233,5395.00,
""
"Abbreviated Performance Totals"
"Event","Performance Date","Discount","Tickets","Face Value Amt",
Event Four,18 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,COMPLIMENTARY,12,0.00,
Event Four,18 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,GENERAL ADMISSION,211,5275.00,
Event Four,18 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,RESERVED,0,0.00,
Event Four,18 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,STUDENT,4,60.00,
Event Four,18 Feb 2013 07:30 PM GMT,Senior Citizen,6,60.00,
,,,233,5395.00,
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following to do this:

```
if(!isset($f))
    {
        $eventDateArray = checkIfEventInArray(trim(substr($line_of_text[0],6)), $eventArray);
    }
if($eventDateArray['result'] == true)
    {
        unset($eventDateArray['result']);
        $f = 1;
        // get event name
        $eventName = trim(substr($line_of_text[0],6));
    }
    if(isset($f))
        {
            if($f == 1 && strpos($line_of_text[0], 'Performance Date:') !== false)
                {
                    $dateCheck = checkIfDateInArray($line_of_text[0], $eventDateArray);
                }
            if($f == 1 && $dateCheck['result'] == true)
                {
                    $eventId = $dateCheck['eventId'];
                    $f = 2;
                }
            if($f == 1 && $line_of_text[0] == 'Abbreviated Performance Totals')
                {
                    unset($f);
                }
```

using the following functions:

```
function selectedEventsArray($array)
    {
        if(is_array($array))
            {
                $editedArray = '"' . implode('","', $array) . '"';
                $eventArray = array();
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id_event, name_event, date_event, time_event FROM event WHERE id_event IN ($editedArray)");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
                        $date = date_create($row['date_event']);
                        $for_date = date_format($date,'d M Y');
                        $time = date_create($row['time_event']);
                        $for_time = date_format($time,'h:i A');
                        $eventDate = "Performance Date:  $for_date $for_time";

                        $eventArray[$row['id_event']] = array($row['name_event'], $eventDate);
                    }
                return $eventArray;
            }
    }

function checkIfEventInArray($str, $eventArray)
    {
        $newArray = array();
        $newArray['result'] = false;
        foreach ($eventArray as $key => $i)
            {
                if(trim(strtolower(strip_tags($str))) == trim(strtolower(strip_tags($i[0]))))
                    {
                        $newArray['result'] = true;
                        $newArray[$key] = $i[1];
                    }
            }
        return $newArray;
    }

function checkIfDateInArray($dateStr, $eventDateArray)
    {
        $newArray = array();
        $newArray['result'] = false;
        foreach ($eventDateArray as $key => $i)
            {
                if (strpos($dateStr, $i) !== false)
                    {
                        $newArray['result'] = true;
                        $newArray['eventId'] = $key;
                    }
            }
        return $newArray;
    }
```